# Spring Boot upgrade from 2.7.6 to 3.1.0

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-security, spring-boot-cloud

We are upgrading our microservices from spring-boot version 2.7 to 3.1.0.

We are using PCF for service development and for service registry we are using Spring Cloud Service RegistryPLAN: standard that comes with PCF.

We also have used the annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient in our bootstrap class. Also we have setup the approriate path in the manifest files.

But when we are trying to deploy the microservice it is giving us "Unable to send hearthbeat" as given below.

com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/fc24a30d-a7e0-475d-5540-31a9 - was unable to send heartbeat!

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

We are upgrading our microservices from spring-boot version 2.7 to 3.1.0.

We are using PCF for service development and for service registry we are using Spring Cloud Service RegistryPLAN: standard that comes with PCF.

We also have used the annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient in our bootstrap class. Also we have setup the approriate path in the manifest files.

But when we are trying to deploy the microservice it is giving us "Unable to send hearthbeat" as given below.

com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/fc24a30d-a7e0-475d-5540-31a9 - was unable to send heartbeat!

Comment: Could you please share the complete errors in code format? It would make it easier for others to read and answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.